# Trinomial distribution conditional mean

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $(X_1,X_2)$ have the trinomial distribution with $n=5$, $p_1=0.2$, $p_2=0.3$

$f\left(x_1,x_2\right)=\frac{5!}{x_1!x_2!\left(5-x_1-x_2\right)!}\left(0.2\right)^{x_1}\left(0.3\right)^{0.3}\left(0.5\right)^{5-x_1-x_2}$

we want to find the conditional mean $E\left(X_2|X_1>0\right)$.

$\because X_2|X_1=x_1\sim Binomial\left(n-x_1,\ \frac{2}{7}\right)$

$ X_2|X_1=1\sim Binomial\left(4,\ \frac{2}{7}\right)$ $\Rightarrow E\left(X_2|X_1=1\right)=4\times \frac{2}{7}$

$X_2|X_1=2\sim Binomial\left(3,\ \frac{2}{7}\right)$ $\Rightarrow 
E\left(X_2|X_1=2\right)=3\times \frac{2}{7} $

$X_2|X_1=3\sim Binomial\left(2,\ \frac{2}{7}\right)$ $\Rightarrow 
E\left(X_2|X_1=3\right)=2\times \frac{2}{7} $

$X_2|X_1=4\sim Binomial\left(1,\ \frac{2}{7}\right)$ $\Rightarrow 
E\left(X_2|X_1=4\right)=1\times \frac{2}{7} $

$X_2|X_1=5=0 $ $\Rightarrow E(X_1|X_1=5)=0$

So $E\left(X_2|X_1>0\right)=\left(5-n\right)\times \frac{2}{7},\ n=1,2,3,4,5$, is the answer correct?